# How to make other form elements clickable when a modal box is in front?

Tags: javascript, html, css

A modal box appears when I focus this field. And it goes whenever I click elsewhere.

[image: modal box and field]

I can't double click to reveal past values because on double clicking, the modal box first appears and then goes, i.e. the second click is not registered as click on text field. How to double click to open list of past values without closing the modal box?

```js
function edifactTagsInfo() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
}

function blurEdifactTagsInfo() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 0;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: red;
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
  opacity: 0.9;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 25px;
  border: 5px solid #0eaadc;
  width: 50%;
  font-family: Amadeus_Font, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #0c65ba;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="edifactTagsField" onfocus="edifactTagsInfo()" onblur="blurEdifactTagsInfo()">

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close"></span>
    <p>TEXT</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Stop calling hide on blur.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
function edifactTagsInfo() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
}

document.getElementById('edifactTagsField').parentElement.addEventListener('click',function() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 0;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: red;
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
  opacity: 0.9;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 25px;
  border: 5px solid #0eaadc;
  width: 50%;
  font-family: Amadeus_Font, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #0c65ba;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="edifactTagsField" onfocus="edifactTagsInfo()">

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close"></span>
    <p>TEXT</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

all what I do is remove hiding the modal **onBlur** event of **edifactTagsField** and add a **onClick** listener to the *parent* of **edifactTagsField** to hide the modal;